# insert null into mysql using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, null

Is there way to insert null into mysql from an empty text field in vb.net

thanks..

Comment: ADO.NET? LINQ to SQL? Entity framework?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using ADO.NET, OleDb and parameters, you need to set the value to **DBNull.Value**

Example:

```
Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
//... set connection string etc

    cmd.Parameters.Add("myFieldName", OleDbType.VarWChar)
    cmd.Parameters("myFieldName").Value = DBNull.Value

//... etc

End Using
```

Comment: im using vb.net, oledb and parameters  `myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter_name", DBNull.Value)`  Returns a .read error  This one works though so I assume DBNull.Value isnt recognized by vb.net when passing to mysql  `myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter_name", "")`

Answer (score 0):

Simply you may use the following as your query string:

```
Dim Query as String = "Update Table set Column = NULL Where ID = " & SomeTextBox.Text
```

You apply that also when you insert.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not working, please check whether the field is **null allowed**.

```
Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
//... set connection string etc

    cmd.Parameters.Add("myFieldName", OleDbType.VarWChar)
    cmd.Parameters("myFieldName").Value = DBNull.Value

//... etc

End Using
```